# how to deduplicate millions of records of custom objects

Tags: apex, custom-object, appexchange, data, duplicate-management

In an org of a client we have about 170 million records of mostly custom objects, with some single custom objects having as much as 70 million records on their own.

The problem is that for about 10 custom objects we have duplicate records. In some cases it's a few hundred duplicates, in others half a million. It goes without saying that this should not be the case, and that the data needs to be deduplicated. The cause of the problem: unchecked 'unique value' checkboxes, and a non-incremental ETL interface with an Oracle ERP backend.

I looked into the following:

1. Writing de-duplication Batchable scripts in Apex, but these only work
   for objects with less than a few million records, as my SOQL
   statements which include `ORDER BY` instructions otherwise time out.
2. Extracting data using Data Loader, processing it externally, and
   deleting duplicate records using Data Loader once more also isn't
   possible, as DL can only handle up to five million records, and does
   not support batched/partial exports (that I know of).
3. SF's built-in
   Duplicate Jobs also isn't an option due to custom object / record
   count limitations.

So far I've come up with the following 'solutions':

- dropping all data, and reloading everything from the external master (Oracle ERP); which would take about three days, and would cause some loss of data
- loading data into an actual database such as Postgres using ETL, deduping everything in the database, and then either mirroring it back, or writing an Apex script which uses the output from a dedupe-query in the DB to delete records in SF; which would be complex and probably quite costly depending on the tools used
- doing the above using Heroku Connect
- spending ~10000 USD or more on a deduping tool that integrates natively with SF

The project manager is getting quite irritated that it's taking so long (have been trying to fix it over the past week), but they don't seem to understand the complexity of the problem. Also, they would like it fixed ASAP, and preferably for free.

Do you people have any ideas on what the best solution to this particularly huge problem?

---

PS: I know that the crappy data model which made this major fail possible in the first place is an ever greater issue, but I only recently joined this project, and my only job right now is to get the data back in a usable state.

Comment: You could do incremental DL exports using some date field to "batch" the downloads, then post-process in another tool, then delete dups via DL again

Comment: @cropredy that won't work on the entire dataset as all the original 170 million records were inserted within three days (so ~56 million / day, which is still way to many records), but it could could just work if I can figure out the dates after which the batches of duplicates were inserted. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You could put an auto number field on all records and then you have something to "batch"